# how do i access a param on more than one post or get

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am asking someone for their name in my post /'startgames' and want to be able to use it across all my posts and gets and i am having issues any help would be appreciated....
Im just starting to learn ruby and more so even sinatra i have made a tictactoe game for both comp and online and i have been coding this game for the computer itself since the i started and i am constantly refactoring as  i learn new stuff so please dont be to hard on me cause im sure im making it way more complicated than need be but its working so far

```
require 'sinatra'
# require_relative "trippy_game_functions.rb"
# trippy = Joestrippygame.new 

get '/startgames' do

answerphone = params[:playgame]

erb :startgame, :locals => {:message1 => "Welcome To Joe's Games. Click the game you wish to play ."}
end

post '/startgames' do

answerphone = params[:playgame]

@playername = @params[:name]
if answerphone == "Joe's Trippy Adventure Game"
    erb :trippygame1, :locals => {:message1 => "#{@playername} Chose to Play Joe's Trippy Adventure Game."}

elsif answerphone == "Jade's Safari Adventure Game"
    erb :safari1, :locals => {:message1 => "#{@playername} Chose to play Jade's Safari Adventure Game."}
else
    erb :startgame, :locals => {:message1 => "Thanks For playing Have a Great Day"}
end
end

post '/answerdoor' do 
answerdoor = params[:door]

@playername = @params[:name]
door = rand(2).floor
if answerdoor.include?('Yes') && door == 0
    # erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{playername} Decides to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " #{playername} your in Luck It's Your good buddy Dave." }
    erb :davehere, :locals => {:daveishere => "Your in Luck ,It's Your Good Buddy Dave.", :message1 => "Whats up #{@playername} #{params[:name]} I'm Thinking about hitting the club up wanna go? "}

elsif   answerdoor.include?('Yes') && door == 1
            # erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{playername} Decides to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " Oh No its The cops." }
                redirect to ('/police')
elsif   answerdoor.include?('No') && door == 0 
            erb :answerdoorno, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{@playername} Decides not to answer the door, but it dosen't Really matter cause Dave walks in anyways."}
elsif   answerdoor.include?('No') && door == 1
            # erb :answerdoorno, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{playername} Decides not to answer the door, but it dosen't Really matter cause its the cops and the bust in."}
                redirect to ('/police')
end
end

get '/police' do
@playername = @params[:name]
erb :police, :locals => {:msg1 => "Fuck I'ts the cops" ,:arrested => "Well damn man. That sucks #{@playername}...." }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most apps you'll want to save user-submitted data someplace, most typically a SQL (or NoSQL) data store.

In this case you could use the [session](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20Sessions) object to persist the username between requests with `session[:name] = params[:name]`, and retrieve it with `session[:name]`.

(See the above linked docs for additional details, such as the need to `enable :sessions` prior to using the session hash.)

But again you'll probably want a database eventually, and you could investigate the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) gem ([ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) library) for that.

Comment: Thanks man, It works now..... One more question if you can help.... How can i make either a (erb) view or a redirect wait a few seconds on a view before it goes to the next one automatically..... I can get it to redirect but it wont wait on the view i want it just skips that one and goes to the next one in line or the redirect page  (what im talking about is in the answerdoor post commented out the erbs it keeps skippin)

Comment: You would want to use javascript for that